# Как реализовать SQL запрос

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Проблема такая, имеется две таблицы, с однй я получаю реестровый номер, а далее я по этому номеру в этой же таблице получаю id записи посредством вложенного запроса. Вот как пример:

```
SELECT id FORM table WHERE reestr_number = (
SELECT reestr_number FROM table GROUP BY reestr_number HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

Далее мне по этому id нужно найти id записи в другой связанной таблице, т.е. ещё один вложенный запрос сделать не получится т.к. запрос может возвращать только одно значение, как я могу получить нужную мне id? Курсор может подойти для данной задачи?
Пытался сделать так:

```
SELECT id FROM table2 t2 INNER JOIN table1 t1 
ON t2.id_первой = t1.id_первой 
WHERE t1.id = (SELECT id FORM table WHERE reestr_number = (
SELECT reestr_number FROM table GROUP BY reestr_number HAVING COUNT(*) > 1));
```

Comment: покажите запрос на поиск следующего id

Comment: Если подзапрос всегда одно значение возвращает, то почему IN не используете? С IN можно сколько угодно подзапросов завернуть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id FROM table2 t2 INNER JOIN table1 t1 
ON t2.id_первой = t1.id_первой 
WHERE t1.id in (SELECT id FORM table WHERE reestr_number = (
SELECT reestr_number FROM table GROUP BY reestr_number HAVING COUNT(*) > 1));
```